# Add watermarktext to image dynamically without saving image to server

Tags: asp.net, image, watermark

I have an image stored on my server in this folder:
\images\freemedia\largethumbs\test.png

On my default.aspx page I have an imagecontrol:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
```

When the visitor requests the default.aspx page I want to get the test.png image from the server, add the watermark text "hello world" to it on the right bottom.
I DON'T want to save the watermarked image to the server, since I want to save storage and still want to have access to the original image.
From the image that is shown to the visitor, he should preferably not be able to derive the original filename, so he should not be allowed to see that the original filename is test.png.

I've been searching on Google a lot, but all examples save the watermarked image to disk, which I don't want.

I already have a httphandler:

```vb
Public Class pichandler : Implements IHttpHandler

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim data As Byte()
    Dim fName As String 

    Using w As New generaltablesTableAdapters.freemediaTableAdapter
        fName = w.GetDataById(i)(0).medialink.ToString
    End Using
    data = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/images/freemedia/thumbs/" & fName))

    ' --> how can I add a watermark text to the image here?!?!?!?

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(data)
End Sub


End Class
```

Does anyone have a code sample on how to do this?

If there's another way of doing this, that is fine too. But please show how I can serve the watermarked image as part of the final HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working with asp.net, you might as well use an [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx).

Here's an example, create a new generic handler, let's call it **ImageHandler** and the code can be as easy as this:

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Clear response and set content type to image.
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        // Create your image, however you want it. Server.MapPath and so on.
        var image = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Images\image.jpg");

        // And save it to the OutputStream.
        image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

And then just use it like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/ImageHandler.ashx" runat="server" />
```

Of course you could also send in some *QueryString* parameters like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/ImageHandler.ashx?filename=myimage.jpg" runat="server" />
```

And then just use `context.Request.QueryString["filename"]` in the ImageHandler.

---

**UPDATE:**

After the comments, here's how you can add a watermark:

```vb
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim watermarkText As String = "Copyright"
    Dim fName As String 

    Using w As New TopTrouwen.generaltablesTableAdapters.freemediaTableAdapter
        fName = w.GetDataById(i)(0).medialink.ToString
    End Using

    ' Create image directly from the path
    Dim image = Drawing.Image.FromFile(context.Server.MapPath("~/images/freemedia/thumbs/" & fName))
    Dim font As New Font("Tahoma", 16, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

    'Adds a transparent watermark 
    Dim color As Color = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)
    Dim brush As New SolidBrush(color)
    Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)

    ' Measure the watermark text so we can offset it's width and height
    Dim watermarkSize = gr.MeasureString(watermarkText, font)

    ' Create the point where the watermark text should be printed
    Dim point As New Point(image.Width - watermarkSize.Width, image.Height - watermarkSize.Height)

    gr.DrawString(watermarkText, font, brush, point)
    gr.Dispose()

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
    image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
End Sub
```

Comment: Funny thing, I already had a http handler. But I don't know how to add a watermark text to the image that is served. I updated my original post with my current httphandler code. Do you know how to add watermark text to that? Thanks!

Comment: I used the code here: http://www.magic-dev.com/upload-images-watermark.htm
But that saves the actual image to disk and does not seem to allow me to save the watermark text to a desired region of the image in a specific font-size, e.g. right bottom corner in font-size 16px. The example code repeats the text through the entire image, which I don't want either.

Comment: @Floran Well, that looked like a lot of code that you won't need. I have added an example to my answer on how you can do it, in VB.

Comment: Thanks for the codesample! Works perfectly! 
I have another related question, since I want to enable fancybox lightbox on the images served by the httphandler. If you want to have a look at it, it's right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850669/is-fancybox-possible-with-a-httphandler

Comment: one more thing: how can I make the background color of the watermark a transparent grey? So a transparant grey block with a solid white text? Thanks again!

Comment: Solved it by drawing a rectangle the size of the watermark: gr.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(color.Red), image.Width - watermarkSize.Width, image.Height - 20, watermarkSize.Width, 20)