# Is Fancybox possible with a httphandler?

Tags: asp.net, fancybox, httphandler

The code below works when I don't serve the images via the httphandler but just add the image URL directly in the HTML.
When I load images via the httphandler, the basic image in the  control is shown correctly, but then when I click that image to load the larger image in a lightbox, I see scrambled code (wierd characters) see this image:

[image]

so I'm assuming Fancybox needs a direct URL to an image to fill the lightbox with, but I'm not sure.
How can I make sure that when the user clicks the hyperlink, fancybox shows the larger image which is served by pichandler.ashx?

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancylink").click(function () {
        var cuRRent = $("a.advance-link img").attr("src");
        cuRRent = cuRRent.replace('largethumbs/', '');
        $.fancybox({
            'href': cuRRent,
            // other API options etc 
            'overlayColor': '#000',
            'opacity': true,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'none'
        }); //fancybox 
    }); //click 

    $("a.freemediaimage").fancybox({
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'overlayColor': '#000',
        'opacity': true,
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'speedIn': 600,
        'speedOut': 200,
        'overlayShow': true
    });

}); // ready 


</script>



<asp:HyperLink ID="hlMediaImage" CssClass="freemediaimage" runat="server">    
    <asp:Image ID="MediaImage" runat="server" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

**Code-behind**

```
hlMediaImage.NavigateUrl = "~/pichandler.ashx?i=2&t=freemediadetails&s=2"  
MediaImage.ImageUrl = "~/pichandler.ashx?i=2&t=freemediadetails&s=1"
```

**pichandler.ashx**

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim data As Byte()


    Dim i As Integer = CInt(context.Request.QueryString("i"))

    Dim type As String = context.Request.QueryString("t")

    Dim fName As String = String.Empty

    If i = 0 Then
        data = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/images/noimage_{0}.jpg", Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)))
    Else


        Select Case type
            Case "freemedia"
                Using w As New generaltablesTableAdapters.freemediaTableAdapter
                    fName = w.GetDataById(i)(0).medialink.ToString                                               
                End Using
                If fName = "" Or fName.Contains("soundcloud.com") Or fName.Contains("youtube.com") Then
                    data = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/images/noimage_{0}.jpg", Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)))
                Else
                    data = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/images/freemedia/thumbs/" & fName))
                End If
            Case "freemediadetails"

                Dim searchquery As New StringBuilder
                searchquery.Append(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("freemedia_solrUrl"))
                searchquery.Append("select/?indent=on&facet=true")
                searchquery.Append("&fq=id:""" + i.ToString + """")
                searchquery.Append("&fl=id,medialink,copyrighttext&q=*:*")
                searchquery.Append("&facet.mincount=1") 'dont show facets which have no value
                searchquery.Append(searchquery.ToString)

                Dim req As HttpWebRequest
                Dim Resp As HttpWebResponse
                Dim reader As StreamReader
                Dim responseString As String
                Dim XPath As String = "response/result"

                req = HttpWebRequest.Create(searchquery.ToString)
                Resp = req.GetResponse()
                reader = New StreamReader(Resp.GetResponseStream)
                responseString = reader.ReadToEnd()

                Dim objXML As New XmlDocument

                objXML.LoadXml(responseString)
                XPath = "response/result"

                Dim root As XmlNode = objXML.DocumentElement
                Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("descendant::doc")

                fName = nodeList(0).SelectSingleNode("str[@name=""medialink""]").InnerText
                Dim watermarkText As String = nodeList(0).SelectSingleNode("str[@name=""copyrighttext""]").InnerText

                Dim size As String = context.Request.QueryString("s")

                ' Create image directly from the path

                dim fpath as string
                If size = "1" Then
                    fpath = "~/images/freemedia/largethumbs/"
                ElseIf size = "2" Then
                    fpath = "~/images/freemedia/"
                End If

                Dim image = Drawing.Image.FromFile(context.Server.MapPath(fpath & fName))
                Dim font As New Font("Tahoma", 16, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

                'Adds a transparent watermark 
                Dim color As Color = color.White 
                Dim brush As New SolidBrush(color)
                Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)

                ' Measure the watermark text so we can offset it's width and height
                Dim watermarkSize = gr.MeasureString(watermarkText, font)

                ' Create the point where the watermark text should be printed
                Dim point As New Point(image.Width - watermarkSize.Width, image.Height - watermarkSize.Height)

                gr.DrawString(watermarkText, font, brush, point)
                gr.Dispose()

                image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg)


            Case Else 'its a general object
                Using w As New genobjectsTableAdapters.genobjects_photosTableAdapter
                    fName = w.GetPhotoById(i)(0).locpath.ToString
                End Using
                data = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/images/objphotos/thumbs/" & fName))


        End Select
    End If


    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"

    If type <> "freemediadetails" Then
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(data)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you visit the URL of the large image (without using fancybox to view it), does the image show correctly?

Comment: yes, when I request /pichandler.ashx?i=2&t=freemediadetails&s=2 directly in the browser I do see the correct image.
I updated my post with an image of what fancybox shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using fancybox v1.3.4 because the API options in your code, aren't you?

If you are linking to an image this way :

```
/pichandler.ashx?i=2&t=freemediadetails&s=2
```

... your link `href` doesn't have any image extension (jpg, png, gif). Because of that, fancybox doesn't know what `type` of content to handle. You need to force the `type` of content to `image` within your fancybox custom script. That is documented here http://fancybox.net/faq, No. 6

Then you could do :

```
$("a.freemediaimage").fancybox({
  // other API options
  "type": "image"
});
```