# Image not displaying on webpage just shows source

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to dynamically display an image with text on it.  There are quite a few examples of this ie [Write Text On An Image in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826921/write-text-on-an-image-in-c-sharp)

For the time being this is the only thing on a visual studio generated empty winform page.
but I continue to get the same result regardless of the technique is use, so perhaps its a problem with my page?

My output page displays like this:

```
 <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="index.aspx.vb" Inherits="testtext.index" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head><title>

 </title></head>
 <body>
 <form method="post" action="./index.aspx" id="form1">
 <div class="aspNetHidden">
 <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="G30FF0+ZAHGhkQJeBgR+oRS6OrykggI6KG2KLa2Mf0lna5zKb83yvLWtkQfnBa4AEDqKkttFuBoZ1lWeDcgqUpLSg0hHsyoD0paxcB2U0Js=" />
</div>

<div>

        <p><img src="data:image/PNG;Base64, �PNG���
 IHDR���5������9堢���sRGB�������gAMA����
 �a���  pHYs�������o�d����IDATHKՓ��0�;�9Nvq�lb����D�     />
</div>

 <div class="aspNetHidden">

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="90059987" />
 </div></form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My code looks like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtmstrong textl">
 <head runat="server">
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
  <%Dim cls = New testtext.clsUtil %>
        <p><img src="data:image/PNG;Base64, <%cls.MakeImage("Testing") %>" />
 </div>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

the function .MakeImage ends as follows:

```
        '// SET ALIGNMENT
    Dim format As StringFormat = New StringFormat
    format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center

    '// DRAW THE FONT
    Dim oMemStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
    g.DrawString(Text, oFont, fgBrush, rectF, format)
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/png"
    img.Save(oMemStream, ImageFormat.Png)
    oMemStream.WriteTo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream)

    '// CLEAN UP
    img.Dispose()
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

The function .MakeImage appears to be working correctly returning the image but sadly no picture is displayed.

Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829106/add-watermarktext-to-image-dynamically-without-saving-image-to-server

Comment: Adding `data:image/PNG;Base64,` to a normal image does not spontaneously make it a Base 64 image. You have to send a string to the page, not a "real" image as you are doing now.

Comment: I'm not sure on the Base64 thing that's just my last attempt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things:
your output is not base64 encoded, and your page output you’ve listed doesn’t have a closing double-quote on src=“...

Let me know if you need code on how to resolve.  Deal with base64 first, in case the current output is messing up the page output.

Cheers!

Added:

use `Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)` to encode your bytes into a Base64 string.

Or, if you want to continue to return bytes to the client, consider just putting an image URL in like `src=“/images.ashx/testing"`, then setting up an ASHX handler to call your image-generating function.  You can return bytes without encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the replay; I tried without the 64, the base64 was just a last ditch attempt to figure out what's going on.  ie <img src="data:image/PNG, <%cls.MakeImage("Testing") %>" />
 The closing quote is after the function call mage("Testing") %> "  />

Comment: @GDutton it won’t work, you can’t do inline images without base64 encoding, and you aren’t doing that now, see my edited answer for details on how to do it.